# Does Ideone support Python command line parameters?

Tags: python, arguments, interpreter

I'm trying to remotely guide a few people in my office toward Python, and the easiest way to do that seems to be showing them how these simple Python samples ...

http://wiki.python.org/moin/SimplePrograms

... run in a sandbox like [ideone.com](http://ideone.com).

All goes well until example eight ("Command line arguments, exception handling").

I am seeing no way to send arguments to the ideone interpreter, and when I try to squeeze values through stdin, they appear to be ignored. Does anyone know how to do this? The ideone FAQ says nothing on the matter of arguments.

If not, is there another web-based Python interpreter that accepts stdin **and** args and might do the trick?

Thanks in advance. You guys are great.

Comment: No, it doesn't. No, there probably aren't any. Why would you want that, anyway? Just use the real interactive interpreter.

Comment: Generally good advice, CPP, I agree. However, I'm trying to convince non-programmers via a single mass-email that this isn't scary **and** that it won't take a lot of their time. For now, that means keeping things generally as simple as possible and not asking them to install any software. It's looking, however, like I might fall back to your option: Most of the other answers on here are certainly clever, but they're probably beyond what I'd ask of my audience. Conversely, PythonAnywhere looks cool, but it doesn't seem to support copying and pasting, which makes a whirlwind tour difficult.

Comment: Using the IDE to process command-line arguments is not as simple as possible.  It's an appallingly bad idea.

Comment: You're right, of course. This would be "simple" for a very specific audience. I should have put quotes around the word the first time.

 :)

Comment: "This would be "simple" for a very specific audience".  Equally false.  It's not simple in any sense of the word.

Comment: In this specific case, and with this specific tutorial audience, asking folks to simulate command lines would be less problematic than asking each of them to spend time installing a Python executable (or even longer having the IT folks install it for them), then requesting that each of them open a big, scary command line -- something some of them haven't touched in three or four years. So maybe we can reboot this and just call it "less laborious for the user" if you like. Either way, I really appreciate all the replies. (I ended up just forking the tutorial, omitting command line examples.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative is [PythonAnywhere](http://www.pythonanywhere.com/). There's an [instant demo](http://www.pythonanywhere.com/try-ipython/), and you can log in to get space to store scripts, and a variety of shells.

When you're logged in, you can start a bash shell, and run Python scripts from the command line with whatever arguments you want.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use ideone, you can ***simulate*** params by extending the `sys.argv` variable. For your example:

```
sys.argv.extend(['3', '4', '5'])
```

Just after `import sys`.

here's the ideone link: http://ideone.com/8pH8A

Comment: Use `shlex` if you want to pass a string and have it split into args just like it's normally done, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12260772/399317).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ideone in Bash mode to run Python with arguments. Since it doesn't let you save files, you can use Bash's heredoc feature to supply the Python script:

[Example](http://ideone.com/tAKn3):

```
python - 1 2 3 <<EOF

import sys
print 'Args: ', sys.argv[1:]

EOF
```

Output:

```
Args:  ['1', '2', '3']
```

The `-` argument tells Python to read the script from standard input. Everything between `<<EOF` and `EOF` is supplied as the standard input to Python. Note that this means you won't be able to read standard input from your script with `raw_input` and similar functions.

Answer (score 0):

ideone doesn't seem to support command-line arguments. It *does*, however, support `stdin`. Underneath the source-code text area, there is a link (as of this writing) that states

> click here to enter input (stdin) or additional note

Here you can enter any kind of textual input, and you can easily read it with `raw_input()`, or just `input()` if you're using Python3.