# How to pass in command line arguments when using ideone?

Tags: c++, python, command-line

I'm using the ideone online interpreter (http://ideone.com/) to test some C++ and Python programs. How do I specify the command line arguments instead of using the STDIN input?

Comment: From what I can tell, it doesn't look like you can.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like you can't, but a *quick hack* should do the trick:

```
static char * const ARGV[] = { "myprog", "hello", "world", NULL };

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    argc = 3;
    argv = ARGV;

    // ...
}
```

Or convert the standard input into args:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<char *> fabricate(std::vector<std::string> & v)
{
    std::vector<char *> res(v.size() + 1, NULL);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != v.size(); ++i) { res[i] = &v[i][0]; }
    return res;
}

std::vector<std::string> args_vector((std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::cin)), std::istream_iterator<std::string>());

std::vector<char *> argv_vector = fabricate(args_vector);


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    argc = args_vector.size();
    argv = argv_vector.data();

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I guess that will have to do. How about for Python programs?

Comment: @lifebalance: err... "similarly"? :-)

Comment: I prefer the 2nd approach. Would appreciate some equivalent python code as well. Thanks!

Comment: @lifebalance: I'm afraid I don't know any Python :-(

Comment: Apart from the usual (#include <iostream>
using namespace std;) do I need anything else for compiling?

Comment: @lifebalance: No no no no. `using namewhatever` is **not** "the usual". More like "condensed evil"!

Comment: @lifebalance: Yeah, sorry, I relaxed the constness a bit to give you the required mutable char pointers. (I also forgot the iostream header.)

Comment: @lifebalance: Yeah, there was an extraneous parenthesis... but I'm sure you saw that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16239/discussion-between-lifebalance-and-kerrek-sb)

Answer (score 5):

In python you can hardcode like this:

```
import sys

print sys.argv
sys.argv[1:] = ["test1", "test2"]
print sys.argv
```

This will output:

```
['prog.py']
['prog.py', 'test1', 'test2']
```

To read from stdin:

```
import sys
import shlex

print sys.argv
sys.argv[1:] = shlex.split(None)
print sys.argv
```

Comment: you could use shlex.split() to parse command line from stdin (to emulate how she'll passes arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Just initialize to simulate the command line arguments

```
static char *argv[] = {"program_name", "1st argument", "2nd argument", NULL};
static int argc = 3;
int main() {

}
```